# https redirection from domain.com to domain.net

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

We are experiencing an issue https redirection from domain.com to domain.net

when any request to https://www.oldomain.com
redirection happening but with untrusted certificate error message.

www.domain.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: www.domain.net, domain.net (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
ItsR

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate for domain.com has been replaced with a certificate for domain.net then the invalid certificate warning you're experiencing is perfectly normal.

The reason being that the SSL handshake happens before the redirect. And as the domain that is being used for the handshake does not match the certificate you will get this error.
Your best bet is to either get a certificate for your old domain as well, or get a SAN on your existing certificate.

[Related issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378217/redirecting-https-server-com-to-https-www-server-com-in-apache) [Second related issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378217/redirecting-https-server-com-to-https-www-server-com-in-apache)

Comment: Domain.com having valid certificate and domain.net having valid certificate installed,still the same error message.               what is SAN? i will check with Godaddy. If it is resolve the ssue.    Thanks.

Comment: @itsramesh Is it possible to link us the domains? So that we may review the issue directly?

Comment: Sure, https://www.ulteamo.com  should redirect to https://www.ulteamo.net

Comment: @itsramesh ulteamo.com has the ulteamo.net certificate attached to it. It needs to have the ulteamo.com certificate attached to it, or otherwise the SSL handshake will fail.

Comment: ulteamo.com has its own certificate and added redirect rules. let me brief you. both servers are different having separate public IP's. during ssl hand shake shows error message. I will recheck it.

Comment: I think your issue is a problem with your virtualhost settings... If you browse to https://www.ulteamo.com and https://ulteamo.com you'll notice the www version has the wrong certificate but the correct website, and the non www version has the correct certificate but still displays the test page.

Comment: https ulteamo.com redirecting to https www.ulteamo.net/                          https www.ulteamo.com is not redirecting and shows ssl negotiation failed. please let me know if am doing wrong in apache my configuration.

Comment: Any suggestion settings need to change in virtualhost